# Algorithm to sort multidimensional array based on multiple criteria

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, sorting, search

Assume we have a table having 6 columns (All integers, unsorted). I want to sort this based on 3 columns with priority order. Is there any algorithm to do this?

I looked up this way:

```
data.sort(key=lambda x: (x[3], x[5], x[4]))
```

But how does this work? Will column 5 disturb the table/multi-dimensional array sorted by column 3? Or does it disturb only if column 3's attributes are same and so sort column 5 under it?

If someone could come up with an existing/new algorithm to do this, it'd be great. This is kind of similar to the famous "Algorithm to create balanced team based on multiple criteria" problem. (Better if the algorithm is Python based)

Comment: This will sort on the tuple (x3, x5, x4) x5 will not overtake x3.

Comment: You can test your code and see if it behaves like you want. If it does, you have no problem! :) (in case you tested all usecases)

Comment: As Moberg said. But if this doesn't suit your needs, can you give a reason? In other words, for a specific example (which you *show* us) it doesn't work as desired, or not as efficient as you want.

Comment: @Moberg I ran it and looks like it sorted it just based on the first attribute, that is column 3 as in "data.sort(key=lambda x: (x[3], x[5], x[4]))". What i want to do is to sort it based on column 3 first, then pick and rank the top 'n' rows and now sort them based on column 5 and then again rank top 'n1' and then sort them according to column 4. Just like analyzing a player based on each skills set such as (Shooting, passing, dribbling) with priority for shooting but not just shooting, he also must have decent dribbling and passing.

Comment: That sorting sounds complex, you will have to explain what is wrong with your given solution and give us a clearer explanation of what you want. A small example.

Comment: Look up "strict weak ordering" before you get too far into that. You may want to sort by a function which takes the shooting, passing, and dribbling scores, then returns a grand composite score.

Comment: @KennyOstrom Checked it and not sure if that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Moberg Please check my previous comment (Before your last comment). Think I've explained it in a very apt manner.

Comment: I said to look up strict weak ordering not because it is a solution, but because failing to know about it can lead to (avoidable) serious errors.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to understand how you want to sort it. Tuples are sorted in lexicographical order. Which means that a tuple on the format Tuple[A, B, C] would get sorted on A first, then on B and lastly on C.

For example, these tuples are listed in descending order:

```
(20, 0, 0)
(10, 100, 1000)
(10, 0, 2000)
(10, 0, 0)
(0, 5000, 0)
(0, 200, 3000)
(0, 100, 1000)
```

The ordering you describe sounds like you want to pick the top n after sorting on the first tuple element and then resort based on the second element. This is more advanced, and I think the intent would be more clear if you sort your stuff in multiple passes.

Answer (score 0):

The method that you show works, and can be extended to multiple columns:

```
my_lst = [['a', 5, 'z'],['a', 5, 'a'], ['b', 9, 'm'], ['a', 2, 'r'], ['b', 7, 'j'] , ['b', 3, 'x']]

my_lst.sort(key = lambda x: [x[i] for i in range(3)])
print(my_lst)

""" Output:
[['a', 2, 'r'], ['a', 5, 'a'], ['a', 5, 'z'], ['b', 3, 'x'], ['b', 7, 'j'], ['b', 9, 'm']]
"""
```

I'm not sure why it works, nor can I find it documented.